# Product of two input in another entry field as default value

Tags: python, tkinter

I just want to product of item quantity and price per unit into amount entry as default value how can i do that...

program codes are

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from tkinter import ttk
import mysql
import mysql.connector
from tkinter import messagebox
import datetime
from datetime import date
from ttkwidgets.autocomplete import AutocompleteCombobox



adde=Tk()     
frm3=Frame(adde)
frm3.place(x=191,y=0,relwidth=1,relheight=1)
frm3.configure(bg='#E5E4E2')

# Unit price
price = Label(frm3, text="Unit Price",bg='#E5E4E2', font=("times new roman", 10)).place(x=555, 
y=290)
price_01 = Entry(frm3)
price_01.place(x=555, y=310, width=70)

# Quantity
qty = Label(frm3, text="Quantity",bg='#E5E4E2', font=("times new roman", 10)).place(x=635, 
y=290)
qty_01 = Entry(frm3)
qty_01.place(x=635, y=310, width=60)

# Amount
amount = Label(frm3, text="Amount",bg='#E5E4E2', font=("times new roman", 10)).place(x=705, 
y=290)
amount_01 = Entry(frm3)
amount_01.place(x=705, y=310, width =100)

adde.title(" Voucher Entry ")
adde.geometry("1400x700")
adde.configure(bg='#659EC7')
adde.mainloop()
```

The user input Price and Quantity and Amount entry should be automatically update with product of price and quantity and that entry can't be editable by user....

Answer (score 1):

It is not completly clear to me what do you need, but if I understood you, you need to create `function` that will handle updating of the product. In the `GUI` part of the code you need to add `button` and pass `updating funtion` to it.

```
button= Button(window, height=1, width=10, text="UPDATE",
                          command=lambda: update_function(product, amount, price))
button_login.pack()
```

Inside function to get data from imput field use `.get()`

example:

```
def update_function(product, amount, price):
    product_data = product.get()
    amount_data = amount.get()
    price_data  =price.get()
    # Rest of your code and updating DB code
```

So in example above, `product, amount and price` passed to the u`pdate function` are `entry fileds`, so by using `.get()` you are geting data that was inputed inside `entry fileds`.

Comment: i mean when user enter value in quantity field and price field the product of both field shall show in amount field without any button press

Comment: Yes , but to update DB you need to get data that is inside that filed and update DB with that data. So thats why i recommended you create button and function to handle updating of the DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind `<KeyRelease>` event on `price_01` and `qty_01`, then calculate the amount in the event callback and update `amount_01`.  I would suggest to change `amount_01` from `Entry` to `Label` if you don't want it editable.

```py
# avoid using wildcard import
import tkinter as tk

def calc_amount(event):
    try:
        price = float(price_01.get())
        qty = int(qty_01.get())
        amount_01['text'] = round(price * qty, 2)
    except ValueError as ex:
        # invalid input in price or qty
        # so clear amount_01
        amount_01['text'] = ''

adde = tk.Tk()

frm3 = tk.Frame(adde)
frm3.place(x=191, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
frm3.configure(bg='#E5E4E2')

# Unit price
tk.Label(frm3, text="Unit Price", bg='#E5E4E2', font=("times new roman", 10)).place(x=555, y=290)
price_01 = tk.Entry(frm3)
price_01.place(x=555, y=310, width=70)
price_01.bind('<KeyRelease>', calc_amount) # call calc_amount on key input
# Quantity
tk.Label(frm3, text="Quantity", bg='#E5E4E2', font=("times new roman", 10)).place(x=635, y=290)
qty_01 = tk.Entry(frm3)
qty_01.place(x=635, y=310, width=60)
qty_01.bind('<KeyRelease>', calc_amount) # call calc_amount on key input

# Amount
tk.Label(frm3, text="Amount",bg='#E5E4E2', font=("times new roman", 10)).place(x=705, y=290)
# change amount_01 from Entry to Label, so it is not editable
#amount_01 = Entry(frm3)
amount_01 = tk.Label(frm3, border=1, relief='sunken', bg='white', anchor='w')
amount_01.place(x=705, y=310, width =100)

adde.title(" Voucher Entry ")
adde.geometry("1400x700")
adde.configure(bg='#659EC7')
adde.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank u ....exactly what i want...